# Prove the inverse transform of unilateral Laplace transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform, inverse-laplace

I'm reading this [article](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e102/lectures/Laplace_Transform/node1.html) and having a question.

Consider a function $f$ and its Laplace transform

$\hspace{3.0cm} F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt$, with $\{s|\text{Re}(s) = 0\} \in \text{ROC}[F(s)]$

The inverse Laplace transform would be $f(t) = \lim_{\omega \to \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma - i \omega}^{\sigma + i \omega} F(s) e^{st} ds$.

Now, consider the case where $\text{Re}(s) = 0$, we can see that

$\hspace{3.0cm} f(t) = \lim_{\omega \to \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{- i \omega}^{i \omega} F(s) e^{st} ds = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(i \omega) e^{i \omega t} d\omega$

is an inverse Fourier transform.

According to Fourier transform, we know that

$\hspace{3.0cm} F(i \omega) = \cal{F}\{f(t)\} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-i\omega t} dt$

But the Laplace transform of $f$, when $\text{Re}(s) = 0$, suggests that

$\hspace{3.0cm} F(i \omega) = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-i \omega t} dt$

It turns out that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-i \omega t} dt = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-i \omega t} dt$ ? This seems wrong to me ? Am I getting wrong somewhere ?

Comment: The answer lies in the fact that your function $f$, if you want to define it on $(-\infty,0]$, would be $0$ there. Then everything works. By the way, I edited your question to include factors of $2\pi$ that you were missing. However, you are stilling missing some in the second part of the answer.

Comment: If you define $f$ in that way, $f(t) = f(t) u(t)$ where $u(t)$ is the heavy-side function. But this assumption isn't stated in the definition of unilateral Laplace transform.

Comment: As written in some [text](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e102/lectures/Laplace_Transform/node16.html), if $f(t) = f(t) u(t)$ then unilateral transform is the same as bilateral transform. But in the other case, unilateral transform is said to be different from bilateral transform

Comment: In your case, you started with $f(t)=f(t)u(t)$ and, in that case, the Laplace transform is a holomorphic function on a right half-plane. Then your inverse Laplace transform is performed on that holomorphic function, with the result being a function $f$ such that $f(t)=f(t)u(t)$. If you want to start with a different $f$, then the issues are different.